# Passing variable value from one function to another in autocomplete with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in using autocomplete jQuery with AJAX call.
When user types something in input field, I post that value with AJAX to controller where I get the values from database and then all these values to the JavaScript in success message. But after that, I'm having problem to use these JSON values for autocomplete. How to fix that?

The view file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>         
          $(function() {

             $("#tags").autocomplete({     
                 source: function( request, response ) {  
                 $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/search_con/user' ;?>",
                          data: {'userA': request.term}, 
                   success: function(msgs)
                          {
                          var a = ["Central Palms Hotel","Hotel Monalisha","asghgjfddas","My hotel added","asdfsdf","asdsadsa"];  

                        response(a);
                         // alert(msgs);
                          }
                 });  
                  }

              });

           });


        </script>


<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

and the controller

```
public function user(){

  $userPart = $_POST['userA'];      

  $result = $this->searchdb->search($userPart) ;

  $list = array();

  foreach ($result as $finaldata) {
    $data= $finaldata->name;
    array_push($list, $data);
  }

  echo json_encode($list); 
}
```

Now my problem is that when i remove static variable a and use msgs for response nothing is shown in autocomplete data and when alert msgs i get the same data as in variable a. is there any mistake in my json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have separate function to fetch the data for autocomplete, can be done like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.post("<?php echo base_url().'index.php/search_con/user' ;?>", {
                userA: request.term
            }, response);
        }
    });
});
```

And because of the *async* nature of ajax you cant do this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/search_con/user' ;?>",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (msgs) {
        data = msgs;
    }
});

alert(data); // undefined
```

Comment: did you try my suggestion, if anything went wrong tell me what exactly the error was please. have you checked the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache), expand the source to view the source.

Comment: yes i have updated my code above according to your suggestion but when i alert msgs i get json encoded data and if i pass these data to response nothing happens but if i used the same alert data as static data i.e. var a= (my alerted data) the autocomplete works fine. So actually my problem is alerted data is not properly taken by response it only works with static variable data. if i have any mistake in my json_encode.....???

Comment: what does `alert(msgs)` print?? have you tried to inspect the javascript console for any errors??

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question and your help now my problem is solved i was missing to add datatype= json in my ajax call